# Python Bokeh basic grouped vbar - simplify x-axis

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

The x-axis is unreadably cluttered for a grouped vbar plot for some very simple data, & I can't find how to fix it.

The intent is to show on a single plot the # of tweets/hr over both the lifetime and last 90 days of a twitter acct.

I already have a working version for just the lifetime data which produces a suitably simple/tidy output.

For the grouped version I want show a simple ticker like the single version & use a colour legend to indicate data label for columns.

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file, export_png
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange, Label, Title
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap    

data = {'hours_active': {0: 11, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 2, 6: 15, 7: 27, 8: 75, 9: 96, 10: 205, 11: 278, 12: 241, 13: 238, 14: 236, 15: 184, 16: 232, 17: 164, 18: 211, 19: 236, 20: 197, 21: 199, 22: 253, 23: 97}, 'ninety_days_hours_active': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 2, 6: 15, 7: 23, 8: 68, 9: 78, 10: 94, 11: 111, 12: 135, 13: 80, 14: 109, 15: 102, 16: 94, 17: 58, 18: 106, 19: 94, 20: 110, 21: 98, 22: 89, 23: 2}}

    hours = [str(i) for i in range(0, 24)]
    days =  ['all', '90']

    data = {'hours' : hours, 'all':list(data['hours_active'].values()), '90': list(data['ninety_days_hours_active'].values())}

    x = [ (str(hour), day) for hour in hours for day in days ]

    counts = sum(zip(data['all'], data['90']), ())

    colors = ['#ffff1a', '#191971']

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts))

    p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), plot_width=500, plot_height=500, title="Tweets All/Last 90 Days", )

    p.toolbar_location = None
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    p.min_border = 40
    p.axis.axis_line_width = 2
    p.y_range.start = 0
    p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source, fill_color=factor_cmap('x', palette=colors, factors=days, start=1, end=2))

    show(p)
```

[Output from above code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfoxm.png)

[Example with suitable x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Eq3.png)

I've chosen to avoid using pandas/dataframes because I want to keep the dependencies as minimal as I can & because it's another package to learn (I'm quite stupid & not a programmer); The data is a subdict of another dictionary that's being used in a bigger program.

But I am not locked into the above code if there is a neater simpler way to do it.

---

**UPDATE**

The suggestion to use dodges was just right.
The following code produces *almost* what I want, but see attached image as a couple of things are not rendering exactly as I'd wish. I haven't bothered with a legend just yet.

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge

with open('dsd_dict') as d:
    ddict = json.load(d)

hours = [str(i) for i in range(0, 24)]  # 'fruits'

data = {'hours' : hours, 'all':list(ddict['hours_active'].values()), '90': list(ddict['ninety_days_hours_active'].values()), '30': list(ddict['thirty_days_hours_active'].values())}

colors = ['#ffff1a', '#338dff', '#191971', 'firebrick']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=hours, plot_width=600, plot_height=500, title="Tweets All/Last 90/30 Days",  toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.min_border = 40
p.y_range.start = 0

# X-AXIS SETTINGS #
p.xaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%'02s")
p.xaxis.axis_label = '24 Hour Clock - UTC/GMT'
p.xaxis.axis_label_standoff = 10
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font = 'dejavu sans'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '8pt'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_color = 'black'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'bold'

r = p.vbar(x=dodge('hours', 0.0, range=p.x_range), top='all', width=0.33, source=source, color=colors[0])

glyph = r.glyph
glyph.line_color = "black"
glyph.line_dash = 'solid'
glyph.line_width = 0.1

p.vbar(x=dodge('hours', 0.33, range=p.x_range), top='90', width=0.33, source=source, color=colors[1])

p.vbar(x=dodge('hours', 0.66, range=p.x_range), top='30', width=0.33, source=source, color=colors[3])

show(p)
```

[Output from updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7agYf.png)

As we can  see, the RHS end is crushed and doesn't show the third bar fully, and the columns don't locate vertically over the x-axis ticks clearly enough. I'd prefer them located *between* ticks so it's clear that the values are from (e.g) 0100 - 0200.

I'm guessing I just need to look into how to tweak the offsets for that, but any further pointers would be most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to rotate the tick labels:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical" # or value in radians works too
```

But is sounds like you don't want the nested hierarchical axis at all. In that case, you should use a [Visual Dodge](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#visual-dodge) instead, so that there is only one level of labels on the axis. Here is a complete example:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=fruits, y_range=(0, 10), plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2015', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#c9d9d3", legend=value("2015"))

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.0,  range=p.x_range), top='2016', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#718dbf", legend=value("2016"))

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2017', width=0.2, source=source,
       color="#e84d60", legend=value("2017"))

p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: OP updated to show a solution with dodges. Still some minor problems, but this approach works well

Comment: For bars as close together as yours you may want to set `line_color` to `None` to avoid overlap. For more space on the end, there are padding options on categorical ranges you can set. Finally if you want the groups to be separated (I can't tell from your description) the easiest thing is to reduce the bar with. Categories have a nominal width of 1, so by setting the bar widths to 0.33 they will take up all the space of each category.

Comment: OK thanks very much. 3 bars was too cluttered. Reduced to 2 & set dodge values to 0.2 & 0.65, with widths 0.4 & 0.45, plus x_range.range_padding to 0.027    Result exactly what I wanted!